# How to disable UserName and Password Form in Keycloak and provide options to choose among multiple IDPs

Tags: keycloak

The realm in keycloak is configured with multiple IDPs like Azure, Okta, Google etc.
But username and password is something that is not needed.

In the browser Authentication flow if I disable Forms instead of "Alternative" the login page appears with "Invalid Username or Password"

Please note I want multiple IDPs buttons to appear in the login page without the Username and Password Login Form.

Not much is documented about this in keycloak documentation.

Comment: But without the username and password how are you going to authenticate those users?

Comment: Provide only the choice of IDPs that are configured for the realm... if there is only one IDP  then automatically I can configure to go to the IDP login... but there are more than one IDPs for the realm.

Comment: As an alternative, you can create (or edit)  a login theme and remove the username/password form

Comment: that theme will then apply for all realms... I would want this realm based and not for all realms.

Comment: Hey. Did you manage to solve this ? I got the same issue there

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom authentication provider to achieve your goal.

1. Instruct Keycloak to assign a specific user attribute to all users arriving from the IDP.
2. Build an authentication provider which checks for that user attribute and denies access.
3. Add the authentication provider to the Browser login flow.
4. Create new theme and adjust templates files to hide login fields and show a user-friendly error if the user fails step 2. Use theme only on relevant realm.

Further details here: https://groups.google.com/g/keycloak-user/c/N9cuqXIBrSA/m/sycLxTZbCAAJ